# pyqt main winow freezes while opening another window

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I am working on a PyQt app which shows CSV files in another window using pandas

The user clicks on the add button and selects a CSV file using a FileDialog. Then pandas will read the dataframe which will be passed to another window where the content will be shown.

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from text_viewer import TextViewer
import sys
import pandas as pnd
from threading import Thread

class MainUI(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainUI, self).__init__()
        self.datas = []
        uic.loadUi('main.ui', self)
        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.listView.setModel(self.model)
        self.load_btn.clicked.connect(self.add_btn)
        self.show()

    def add_btn(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        allowed_extensions = "CSV Files (*.csv)"
        files = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Choose Data File To Load", "", allowed_extensions, options=options)
        if files:
            thread = Thread(target=self.add, args=(files,))
            thread.start()

    def add(self, files):
        for file in files[0]:
            try:

                if file.endswith(".csv"):
                    df = pnd.read_csv(file)
                    viewer = TextViewer(df)

                if df is not None:
                    self.datas.append(df)
                    item = QStandardItem(file)
                    self.model.appendRow(item)


            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**text_viewer.py**

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow


class TextViewer(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, df):
        super(TextViewer, self).__init__()
        self.df = df
        uic.loadUi('text_viewer.ui', self)
        self.show() # at this point the main window freezes
```

When I select the file, a new instance of TextViewer is created and at that point the main window freezes. If I don't call show nothing happens but if I do the app freezes until I manually shut it from Task Manager.

Comment: The GUI should not be modified from another thread, change `thread = Thread (target = self.add, args = (files,))
             thread.start ()` by `self.add(files)`

Comment: How many rows and columns does your CSV have?

Comment: @eyllanesc I don't have a problem reading the CSV file. The problem occurs when I try to open another window

Comment: How do you know that is the problem? How have you identified that this line is the problematic one? I have created a lot of GUI and I have never had problems with the show method.

Comment: Remove the thread since Qt prohibits updating the GUI from another thread, perhaps that is what causes the problem.

Comment: I tried to open the window separately and I got this error : QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget. But have already created a QApplication oject in main.py

Comment: When you say: *I tried to open the window separately*, what does that mean? Have you created an `app = QApplication (sys.argv)`?